# How can I iterate dataframe column names for ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

I have a dataframe

```
bbb <- as.data.frame(list(X1 = c(19, 12, 6, 17, 8, 14, 19, 22, 20, 21, 23, 19), 
                                X2 = c(12, 6, 11, 9, 9, 9, 19, 18, 21, 22, 21, 23), 
                                X3 = c(19, 12, 13, 13, 12, 5, 23, 19, 14, 19, 20, 20), 
                                X4 = c(12, 12, 12, 16, 9, 10, 21, 19, 19, 21, 16, 21), 
                                X5 = c(12, 10, 7, 6, 11, 10, 15, 20, 24, 19, 19, 24),
                                cluster = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)))
```

and I would like to use ANOVA to get p-values from each column. I can do it one by one, but how can I do it in a loop? aov does not understand data from `colnames(bbb)`

```
summary(aov(X1 ~ cluster, data = bbb))[[1]]$'Pr(>F)'[1]
```

I need to iterate my dataframe and extract p-values into a vector

Comment: It doesn't solve the whole problem, but there are `summary` methods for multiple responses in `aov` - `summary((aov(cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5) ~ cluster, data = bbb)))` for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the `map()` function from the [purrr package](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) (part of the tidyverse), e.g.

```r
library(purrr)

bbb <- as.data.frame(list(X1 = c(19, 12, 6, 17, 8, 14, 19, 22, 20, 21, 23, 19), 
                          X2 = c(12, 6, 11, 9, 9, 9, 19, 18, 21, 22, 21, 23), 
                          X3 = c(19, 12, 13, 13, 12, 5, 23, 19, 14, 19, 20, 20), 
                          X4 = c(12, 12, 12, 16, 9, 10, 21, 19, 19, 21, 16, 21), 
                          X5 = c(12, 10, 7, 6, 11, 10, 15, 20, 24, 19, 19, 24),
                          cluster = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)))

summary(aov(X1 ~ cluster, data = bbb))[[1]]$'Pr(>F)'[1]
#> [1] 0.004145981

map(bbb, ~summary(aov(.x ~ cluster, data = bbb))[[1]]$'Pr(>F)'[1])
#> $X1
#> [1] 0.004145981
#> 
#> $X2
#> [1] 1.614913e-06
#> 
#> $X3
#> [1] 0.01052767
#> 
#> $X4
#> [1] 0.0001252443
#> 
#> $X5
#> [1] 7.91075e-05
#> 
#> $cluster
#> [1] 4.842692e-159
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This outputs the results in a list, but you can `unlist()` the results or coerce them to a dataframe if required

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create the dataframe
bbb <- as.data.frame(list(X1 = c(19, 12, 6, 17, 8, 14, 19, 22, 20, 21, 23, 19), 
                          X2 = c(12, 6, 11, 9, 9, 9, 19, 18, 21, 22, 21, 23), 
                          X3 = c(19, 12, 13, 13, 12, 5, 23, 19, 14, 19, 20, 20), 
                          X4 = c(12, 12, 12, 16, 9, 10, 21, 19, 19, 21, 16, 21), 
                          X5 = c(12, 10, 7, 6, 11, 10, 15, 20, 24, 19, 19, 24),
                          cluster = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)))

# Vector to store p-values
p_values <- numeric()

# Perform ANOVA and extract p-values for each column
p_values <- lapply(names(bbb)[1:5], function(col) {
  aov_result <- summary(aov(as.formula(paste(col, "~ cluster")), data = bbb))
  p_value <- aov_result[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[1]
  return(p_value)
})

# Print the p-values
print(p_values)
```